# CSS mobile device media query independent of width

Tags: css, media-queries

I am using a dragscroll plugin to pan over some content, but for some reason I have not managed to figure out for a long time the dragscroll does not work on mobile devices.

To clarify: with mobile devices I mean devices without a mouse cursor but with a touchscreen (mobile phones and tables).

The rule for the container is `overscroll: hidden` but I would need to set it to `overscroll: auto` for mobile devices so we can pan over the container.

However, all media queries rely on device width, rather than *type*, so I am stuck with doing something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
    .dragscroll-container {
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

But what if the device has a screen width higher than 768px? Sure, it is odd, but if it happens, we will not be able to pan over the container because the `overflow: auto` rule will not be applied.

Is there a media query that includes portable devices in general, regardless of device width?

Comment: There is no media query for “are you a mobile device”. And my laptop computer _is_ a “portable” device as well, all I have to do is remove all wires ... but that probably would not trigger the problem - whatever that actually is. Your question is unclear, and doesn’t make much sense in its current form, IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe why is it unclear? I can accept "There is no media query for “are you a mobile device”." as a valid answer, I did not actually know it did not exist. You don't have to be condescending, it is not unreasonable to think there is a specific media query for mobile devices. I would also like to know your argument against my question, why is it unclear? I completely disagree.

Comment: It is unclear because you did not properly describe why you would need to discern between “portable” and non-portable devices in the first place. Ok, so something is not working “on mobile” - why? How is that _specific_ to “portable” devices? Are you even sure that you mean portable devices, and not perhaps rather devices with a touchscreen/no mouse, or something like that …?

Comment: I did mean devices with a touchscreen (mobile phones and tablets) and not just any portable device, forgive my wording. I did describe the reason why I need what I am asking: I am experiencing an issue with a dragscroll plugin, and for some reason I have not been able to explain so far (and I'd been at it for a long time), the drag motion on a touch screen is not triggering the scroll. This happens in mobile, tablet, or even the Chrome device toolbar mode. This issue is the reason why I need to set `overflow: auto` in devices with a touchscreen.

Comment: CSS can't do that. And JS not really either, see http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/ But https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+touchscreen should give enough input as to what methods might be applicable to perform an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like your best bet is to explicitly specify the CSS for each mobile device. Chris Coyier was kind enough to publish all the media queries you'll need to do so here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/